# Compiler cannot infer template argument used as return type

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Let's look at this sample:

```cpp
template <typename ReturnType>
ReturnType foo()
{
    return ReturnType{};
}

int main()
{
    int f = foo(); // error
 
//  auto f = foo<int>() works

    return 0;
}
```

This is the compiler output:

```
candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'ReturnType'
```

If it's a rule of the standard, why it has been decided to be like that ?

Also, is there any solution/workaround to omit this first template argument ?

Comment: Template argument deduction doesn't work using return type. [return type does not take part in type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612979/12002570).

Comment: Thanks I already noticed that it does not work but why is it like that ? Is there any specific reason ?

Comment: Yes, because the c++ standard rules says that. You're welcome. [Generally it is not possible to deduce function based on its return type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205136/12002570). Simplest reason is **because when calling a function we do not specify the return type**.

Comment: I mean it should be a trivial feature to implement no ? Unless there are specific reasons to not implement it

Comment: Even though `f` is declared as an `int` this does not mean that it is required to be initialised with an `int` for example `foo();` could return a `char`, `float` etc and this would be valid.  So to avoid the compiler having to guess the code needs to explicitly provide the return type.

Comment: @syl Simplest reason is  **because when calling a function we do not specify the return type** so how is deduction supposed to work here.