candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T' with std::variant
I've been reading all the other questions related to this error and could not find something suitable to my case (or I did not understood them correctly).
I present a minimal example of a class holding a std::variant which represents a variant value (the exception and error handling is omited for brevity):
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

class Value {
    public:
        Value(const std::string&);
        Value(const int&);

        template<typename T> const T& GetValue() const;

    private:
        std::variant<int, std::string> m_value;
};

Value::Value(const std::string& val):m_value(val) {}
Value::Value(const int& val):m_value(val) {}

template<> const int& Value::GetValue<int>() const {
    return std::get<int>(m_value);
}

template<> const std::string& Value::GetValue<std::string>() const {
    return std::get<std::string>(m_value);
}

int main() {
    Value v_int { 666 };
    Value v_str { "Hola" };

    // int i = v_int.GetValue(); // ERROR
    int i = v_int.GetValue<int>(); // OK but not desireable
    // std::string s = v_str.GetValue(); // ERROR
    std::string s = v_str.GetValue<std::string>(); // OK but not desireable

    std::cout << "i: " << i << " s: " << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

What I don't understand is why the // ERROR calls are not deductible if int and std::string are not convertible to each other and target variable destination is the correct type.
Even if manually calling GetValue<T> that would defy the purpose of the wrapping class.
Is calling the non explicit version even possible? Please, if possible do not limit to just present a solution but it would be appreciated an explanation of why it is not working so I can learn from my mistakes.

The compiler cannot duduce the type for the template based on the type of variable you assign the return value to.

To avoid repetition of the type, you can also write auto i = v_int.GetValue<int>();. Why is your code not possible? Because v_int.GetValue() itself is not possible (there is nothing to deduce the template argument from). Whether you are then trying to assign the return value to something is irrelevant.

Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612961/580083

a template converting operator can work : template 
operator const T &() const {return std::get(m_value);}

I thought since C++ is strictly typed and int and std::string are not convertible to each other the target type should be deduced correctly as it is not possible to store an int in std::string and vice-versa and that can be known in compile time

You might use conversion operator:
class Value {
public:
    Value(const std::string&);
    Value(const int&);

    auto GetValue() const
    {
        struct {
            const std::variant<int, std::string>& m_value;

            operator int() const { return std::get<int>(m_value); }
            operator const std::string&() const { return std::get<std::string>(m_value); }    
        } w{m_value};
        return w;
    }

private:
    std::variant<int, std::string> m_value;
};

Demo
But not sure it is a good idea.

Why are you not sure it is a good idea? I used this example to learn more :)

To handle it correctly, you have to handle possible exception (std::bad_variant_access) if type mismatch. idomatic way to handle std::variant is std::visit. Implicit conversion might be surprising, having getInt/getString is simple and explicit.

Thanks, yes, as I said I don't aim for simplicity but learning and as you said, while doing GetValue<int> or GetValue<std::string> or even GetString() or GetInt() is simple, readable and effective, I was just wondering why this don't work as in compile time all needed info is known and unambiguous, but now I know that return types do not count for template deduction (while IMHO they should when there is no ambiguity)

@StormByte "but now I know that return types do not count for template deduction" — In your case, it's not about the return type itself. You should say that "what you do with the returned value does not count for template deduction".

@StormByte As for your "while IMHO they should when there is no ambiguity", I think that you don't know C++ that well to consider all the possible consequences (neither do I). But there are some relevant posts for this problem, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205611/580083 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205075/580083.
